# Is there a way to provide file download without reading the file from path in Java?

Tags: java, file, outputstream

In my program I have a getRequest (JavaSpark) that offers me an Excel file created in Java for download.

To do this, I create the Excel file, save it in a folder and then read the file via the path.

Works.

Code - ExcelCreation:

```
public void createPlanWorkbook() throws Exception {
    ...
    ... 
    do something with workbook...

    workBook.write("C:\\Users\\Develope\\Desktop\\Excel.xlsm");
}
```

Code - request:

```
get("/excelfile", ((request, response) -> {
    response.header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Excel.xlsm;");

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Develope\\Desktop\\Excel.xlsm");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.raw().getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    outputStream.flush();
    return response;
}));
```

I wonder if there is another way to implement this. Is the step of saving and then reading the file necessary? Or is there a way to put the file directly from Javaobject into the request.

For example:

```
outputStream.write(ExcelCreaterObject().getWorkbook());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? In your code example, you are not creating or saving any file on the filesystem - you are simply opening it for reading. Then you read all of its bytes to the memory, and write those bytes to the response output stream.

Comment: Yes, changed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using <s>Apache POI</s> SmartXls to create an Excel workbook. Looking at its Javadoc, it seems that the `Workbook.write` method accepts an outputstream to write to.
[image]

So, you should be able to do write to the response stream directly, something like:

```java
get("/excelfile", ((request, response) -> {
    response.header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Excel.xlsm;");
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Develope\\Desktop\\Excel.xlsm");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.raw().getOutputStream();
    // do some stuff with the workbook
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    return response;
}));
```

Comment: I'm using SmartXLS to write the Workbook... I´m wondering if there is a way to do this without writing the workbook to a folder and reading the file from the folder to the request...

Comment: Same answer still applies - I have edited the answer to reflect that. You can write the Workbook object directly into the response's OutputStream, bypassing the filesystem completely.